# data is undefined in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a bar chart but when I try to animate it accordingly to the data I provided I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'grootte' of undefined
```

I am trying to load in an csv file but whatever I try I either get the error that I can't reference the data or I have the problem that it doesn't recognize the data as integers.

This is the relevant code:

var dataset = []

```
    d3.csv("/csv/test.csv", function(data) {
            dataset = data.map(function(d,i) {

              return {
                grootte: +d.grootte,
                verhuizingentilburg: d.verhuizingentilburg
              };
            });
        });

        //Here we set up the bars with a height of 0, we'll animate them later. The timeout is set for loading data

    bars = svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d, i){
                    return i * (width / dataset.length);
                    console.log(d[0].grootte);
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return height - marginBottom;
                })
                .attr("width", width / dataset.length - padding)
                .attr("height", 0)
                .attr("fill", "rgb(128, 89, 183)");

 var timer = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

    function myTimer() {

        //If the 'amount' radio button is checked, animate it like this

         if(document.getElementById('amount').checked){
            bars.data(dataset);
            bars.transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .delay(function(d, i){
                    return i * 100;
                })
                .attr("height", function(d, i) {
                  console.log(dataset[i].grootte);
                    return yscale(dataset[i].grootte);
                })
                .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                    return (height - marginBottom) - yscale(dataset[i].grootte);
                })
                .attr("fill", "rgb(193, 38, 38)");
            } 
}
```

The problem occurs on the following code:

```
.attr("height", function(d, i) {
              console.log(dataset[i].grootte);
                return yscale(dataset[i].grootte);
```

Can someone help me? That would really help me out!

Comment: looks like you havent instantiated your data yet

Comment: Maybe D3 hasn't finished initializing the global `dataset` variable (this is sketchy, btw) before your timer starts firing?

Comment: I managed to resolve that issue by increasing the timer, but now I get the following error! Error: <rect> attribute height: Expected length, "NaN".

Comment: Looks like there is no value for the height somewhere. The d3.csv is asynchronous so wait until that has finished and then start the timer. I would create a function to start the viewer and call it at the end of the data fetch :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, the call back function of d3.csv waits until the data is loaded. Because of this, the timeout is unneeded. With the timeout and d3.map I believe that the approach is somewhat over complicated.

I got the mechanics to work with few modifications (and I like the look). Rather than map(), I used forEach() which is up to the task. Then, to avoid a timeout function, and because I like d3's functionality, I used a d3 selection rather than getElementById.

You didn't post the whole code, so I don't know what your y scale is (and haven't included it), or various parameters, but the key portion could look like:

```
d3.csv("test.csv", function(data) {

data.forEach( function(d) {
    d.grootte = +d.grootte;
});

var bars = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i){ return i * (width / data.length); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return height - marginBottom;       })
    .attr("width", width / data.length - padding)
    .attr("height", 0);

var button = d3.select("#amount").on("change", function() {
    bars.transition()
        .attr("height",function(d) {
            return d.grootte;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return (height - marginBottom - d.grootte);
        })
        .duration(1000)
        .delay(function(d,i) {
            return i * 100;
        })
});
});
```